# How to make a rectangular coil shape

Tags: materials

I have seen this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YY7XBpAeWE)

I want to make this coil curve shape **but in rectangular shape**

In the video its shown in the circle way. But i want to make in the rectangular way. I want my mesh to go in the rectangular way with the curve edge at corners. How can i spin im not getting it.

[image]

With the reference video i tried to make but fail to make that shape. Is there a way with a quick way i can make it. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with a spiral and stretch it to a rectangle.
[image]

Comment: Thats perfect. Can u plz make your answer little bit in detail plz

Comment: I added a gif. If you have more questions, please ask.